# UltraEdit: keyboard-only way to switch focus in split view?

Tags: windows, ultraedit

Using the keyboard is it possible to switch focus between
the two panes of text when in split mode? (Split mode
started by menu command Window/Split Window.)

I am already using the keyboard for almost all operations in
UltraEdit, including Ctrl+TAB to switch between open
documents. I am yet to find a way to use the keyboard to
switch between the split panes in a document.

Platform: [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) v14.2, Windows XP SP2 64 bit.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Tab?

Comment: That switches between the open documents, not between the split panes in a document. I am using Ctrl+Tab at least 500 times per day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>F6</kbd> to switch focus between the two panes of text in split mode.

I found the solution by going to menu Advanced/Configuration/Key Mapping and pressed button "Show key mapping in editor" to get the list of keyboard shortcuts into an editor window. I then searched for "focus" and this one seemed to fit the bill (and it did):

```
F6    FocusNextPane    Switch to next window pane
```

(Note that the cursor in a pane may not be visible and thus there isn't any indication whatsoever which pane has focus (at least not in older versions of UltraEdit). The workaround is to do some non-editing action, like pressing the right arrow, <kbd>→</kbd>. This will bring the blinking cursor into view and thus indicate which pane has focus.)

Answer (score 1):

Under Advanced, Configuration you can set hot keys to whatever you want to switch the views.